# Drupal 7 services_entity field partial search

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is there a way to do a partial search on a field using services_entity?

Example:

Node title: This is the best title ever

I'd like to find this with something like:
entity_node?parameters[title]=best

Answer (score 0):

I did this by utilizing services views.

I created a view with an exposed filter.

The URL looks like this:

/(service endpoint)/views/(view name)?title=best

Works perfect!